# Nested attributes using paperclip rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-attributes, activemodel

I am new to rails and I am trying to work with nested attributes.
The main idea is to have a a deal(offer) model, a deal will have multiple deal_photos from paperclip.
I have already watched Ryan's Railscast for nested forms and read many articles with many tips regarding problems on the same issue but still it doesn't work for me.

Here is my Implementation:

```
    class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :deal_photos, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_photos
    end


    class DealPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :deal
     has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :large => "600x170", :medium => "250x250!",         :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => lambda { |photo| photo.instance.set_default_url}

     def set_default_url
      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')
     end
    end
```

In my deals controller:

```
    class DealsController < ApplicationController
     def new_deal
  @deal=Deal.new()
      @user= User.find(params[:id])
      3.times { @deal.deal_photos.build }
     end

    def create
     @deal = Deal.new(deal_param)
     @user= User.find(params[:user_id])
     if @deal.save
        @user.deals << @deal
        flash[:notice]="Thank you"
     end
    end

    def edit
     @deal=Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
     3.times { @deal.deal_photos.build }
    end

    def update
     @deal=Deal.find(params[:id])
     if @deal.update_attributes(deal_params)
      flash[:notice]="Deal updated successfully"
     end
    end

    private
    def deal_params
    params.require(:deal).permit(:title, :description, :contact_num, :user_id,    :deal_photos_attributes => [ :id, :caption, :photo, :deal_id])
    end
```

Finally in my form for a new deal:

```
    <%= form_for(:deal, :url=>{:action=>'create', :user_id=> @user.id}) do |f| %>

      <label>Title<b style="color:red;">*</b>
      <%= f.text_field(:title, :placeholder=>"") %>
      </label>
```

------------more fields---------------------

```
      <%= f.fields_for :deal_photos do |builder| %>
        <div>
          <%= builder.label :caption, "Image Caption" %>
          <%= builder.text_field :caption %>

          <%= builder.label :photo, "Image File" %>
          <%= builder.file_field :photo %>
        </div>
      <%end%>

      <%= button_tag("Create", :class=> "secondary button", :button_type => "submit") %>
```

(I have migrated the db for deals_photo to accept paperclip)

The above, creates a form with all fields but instead of 3 inputs for file upload shows only one. It creates 3 empty associations @deal.deal_photos but even if I choose one image to upload from the form it doesn't save it.
If you have any useful advices or another similar question please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in your `deal_param` method?
Do you permit deal_photos' attributes in it?
If no then do something like

> ```
> def deal_params
>  params.require(:deal).permit(deal_attr1, deal_attr2,...., deal_photos_attributes: [:deal_photo_attr1, ...])
> end
> ```

Also, do you get a `deal_id` in your `deal_photos` in view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I 've updated the questions so you can see the deals_params. Yes I get the deal_id in view.

Comment: I suppose you are visiting the new_deal action in your controller.
So the @deal is a new instance and the deal_photos dont get a deal_id. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know, the build action is an alias of the new action. This implementation creates the 3 instances and the associations between them but it is not generates three input fields. Only one field is generated and it is not uploading the picture that I choose.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem in the new_deal.html.erb when I replaced the:

```
    <%= form_for(:deal, :url=>{:action=>'create', :user_id=> @user.id}) do |f| %>
```

with

```
    <%= form_for(@deal, :url=>{:action=>'create', :user_id=> @user.id}) do |f| %>
```

What is changed is that the second line is for the specific new deal instance. Maybe the reason that the first was not working is that the deal_photos didn't get the deal_id, as Alexphys said. But still I haven't figure out the exact reason.